# Import profile VS Select existing - deployment in Azure app service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-appservice

I have .net core web application developed in VS 2019 already running in Azure. I installed the VS 2019 in a new system and opened the solution. When I am trying to publish (may be after a simple code change) the application using Visual Studio. The window that is coming up having 3 options to publish. Regarding these options, what is the difference, and when to use what?

Below is the screenshot, options highlighted in red. Create New is for complete new deployment, as per my understanding. However, I'm not able to clearly get, **"select Existing" versus "import profile"** and when to use what?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The window that is coming up having 3 options to publish. Regarding these options, what is the difference, and when to use what?

1.**`Create New`** option enables us to create a new App Service, create or use an existing App Service plan (**Hosting Plan**) and Resource group within your specific subscription, like below.

If you do not have any existing App Services that you create through Azure portal or VS etc, you can use this option to create a new one before you publish your project.

[image]

2.**`Select Existing`** option enables us to search and select existing App Services from specific subscription and Resource group.

If you'd like to publish your project to an existing App Service, you can use this option.

[image]

3.**`Import Profile...`** option provides a way to import [publish settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/tutorial-import-publish-settings-azure?view=vs-2019) that we got from Azure portal as below and then deploy our app.

Sometimes, developer does not sign in with same account (create Azure App Service etc resources using this account) in Visual Studio, to deploy app to an existing App Service, we can use this option and import a publish settings file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can you download the publish profile from the azure portal for the service in question and reimport it?